# (Android P) Constraint on getting GPS Location in background?

Tags: android, gps, android-sensors, locationmanager, android-9.0-pie

In short, 
are there any new restrictions on getting GPS by [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) when the app is in the background in Android P?

According to the document [Android P Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#all-apps), accessing user input and sensor data is limited when the app is in the background. My concern is whether these new constraints have any impacts on the LocationManager? Perhaps the system location service needs some support of [sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html), so getting gps will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will definitely have an effect of the location services but you should not concern yourself till android p APIs are confirmed. I.e until beta 3 is released